# Multiplos tipos de autenticação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Em meu sistema preciso ter dois tipos de autenticação uma para Usuario comum que irá se registrar e etc.. e outra para o administrador minha pergunta é como eu diferencio as duas autenticação utilizando o FormsAuthentication, acredito que terá algum conflito por exemplo quando eu guardar os valores em:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

Procurei alguns exemplos no Google mas não obtive muito sucesso! entendi mais ou menos que seria necessário criar regras diferentes.

Qualquer coisa será bem vinda! exemplos, links, artigos ...

Comment: Por exemplo quando eu colocar o atributo [Authorize] na minha action como ele vai saber qual tipo de usuário ele vai autorizar?

Comment: Qual versão do seu AspNetMVC ? tem solução sim !!! só vai depender mesmo da versão!

Comment: Estou utilizando o AspNetMVC 4! @Crood pode passar algum link ou exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: da uma olhadela nesse projeto https://github.com/cleytonferrari/LoginMemberShip tem um exemplo prático de `CustomRules`

Comment: Só mais um detalhe eu preciso que ambos os usuários tenham sessões independentes sendo possível existir até as duas ao mesmo tempo! é possível fazer isso com CustomRules ?

Comment: Sim pois em meu projeto a Entidade "Administrador" é diferente da entidade "Usuario" e ambos terão acesso a intefaces diferentes! eu penso se ambos os usuários terão acesso a interfaces diferentes no sistema, talvez a solução seja criar um outro projeto na mesma Solution pra parte administrativa?

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a sua pergunta, você já está utilizando o Form Authentication do ASP.NET.

Para implementar diferentes funções para seus usuários (Administrador, Usuário), você pode utilizar o Membership Roles.

Por exemplo:

```
Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View("Edit");
}
```

Você pode verificar se o usuário está em um grupo de funções assim:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    ...
}
```

Para utilizar o Membership Roles, após você criar uma Web Application no Visual Studio, entre no site de configuração do ASP.NET e adicione as funções de acordo com a sua aplicação.

Um bom tutorial se encontra no próprio site do ASP.NET:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

Uma aplicação de exemplo que utiliza esses frameworks é a MVC Music Store, encontrado em:

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com